Migration to VRF 2.5 - Resolving conflicts between Chainlink VRF v2.5 and OpenZeppelin contracts in Solidity
I'm developing a smart contract using Solidity 0.8.19, integrating Chainlink VRF v2.5 and OpenZeppelin contracts. I'm encountering several conflicts and compilation errors.
Here you can find the github repo I'm working on:
https://github.com/Giulianomlodi/foundry-pizza-vrfv2_5
These are the errors I'm getting in console:
Error: 
    Compiler run failed:
    Error (5883): Event with same name and parameter types defined twice.
      --> lib/chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/shared/access/ConfirmedOwnerWithProposal.sol:13:3:
       |
    13 |   event OwnershipTransferred(address indexed from, address indexed to);
       |   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    Note: Other declaration is here:
      --> lib/openzeppelin-contracts/contracts/access/Ownable.sol:33:5:
       |
    33 |     event OwnershipTransferred(address indexed previousOwner, address indexed newOwner);
       |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    
    Error (7723): Data locations of parameters have to be the same when overriding non-external functions, but they differ.
       --> src/LazyPizza.sol:154:5:
        |
    154 |     function fulfillRandomWords(
        |     ^ (Relevant source part starts here and spans across multiple lines).
    Note: Overridden function is here:
       --> lib/chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/vrf/dev/VRFConsumerBaseV2Plus.sol:135:3:
        |
    135 |   function fulfillRandomWords(uint256 requestId, uint256[] calldata randomWords) internal virtual;
        |   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    
    Error (6480): Derived contract must override function "_transferOwnership". Two or more base classes define function with same name and parameter types.
      --> src/LazyPizza.sol:14:1:
       |
    14 | contract LazyPizzeria is
       | ^ (Relevant source part starts here and spans across multiple lines).
    Note: Definition in "ConfirmedOwnerWithProposal": 
      --> lib/chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/shared/access/ConfirmedOwnerWithProposal.sol:48:3:
       |
    48 |   function _transferOwnership(address to) private {
       |   ^ (Relevant source part starts here and spans across multiple lines).
    Note: Definition in "Ownable": 
      --> lib/openzeppelin-contracts/contracts/access/Ownable.sol:95:5:
       |
    95 |     function _transferOwnership(address newOwner) internal virtual {
       |     ^ (Relevant source part starts here and spans across multiple lines).
    
    Error (6480): Derived contract must override function "owner". Two or more base classes define function with same name and parameter types.
      --> src/LazyPizza.sol:14:1:
       |
    14 | contract LazyPizzeria is
       | ^ (Relevant source part starts here and spans across multiple lines).
    Note: Definition in "ConfirmedOwnerWithProposal": 
      --> lib/chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/shared/access/ConfirmedOwnerWithProposal.sol:43:3:
       |
    43 |   function owner() public view override returns (address) {
       |   ^ (Relevant source part starts here and spans across multiple lines).
    Note: Definition in "Ownable": 
      --> lib/openzeppelin-contracts/contracts/access/Ownable.sol:56:5:
       |
    56 |     function owner() public view virtual returns (address) {
       |     ^ (Relevant source part starts here and spans across multiple lines).
    
    Error (6480): Derived contract must override function "transferOwnership". Two or more base classes define function with same name and parameter types.
      --> src/LazyPizza.sol:14:1:
       |
    14 | contract LazyPizzeria is
       | ^ (Relevant source part starts here and spans across multiple lines).
    Note: Definition in "ConfirmedOwnerWithProposal": 
      --> lib/chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/shared/access/ConfirmedOwnerWithProposal.sol:26:3:
       |
    26 |   function transferOwnership(address to) public override onlyOwner {
       |   ^ (Relevant source part starts here and spans across multiple lines).
    Note: Definition in "Ownable": 
      --> lib/openzeppelin-contracts/contracts/access/Ownable.sol:84:5:
       |
    84 |     function transferOwnership(address newOwner) public virtual onlyOwner {
       |     ^ (Relevant source part starts here and spans across multiple lines).
    
    Error (6480): Derived contract must override modifier "onlyOwner". Two or more base classes define modifier with same name.
      --> src/LazyPizza.sol:14:1:
       |
    14 | contract LazyPizzeria is
       | ^ (Relevant source part starts here and spans across multiple lines).
    Note: Definition in "ConfirmedOwnerWithProposal": 
      --> lib/chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/shared/access/ConfirmedOwnerWithProposal.sol:64:3:
       |
    64 |   modifier onlyOwner() {
       |   ^ (Relevant source part starts here and spans across multiple lines).
    Note: Definition in "Ownable": 
      --> lib/openzeppelin-contracts/contracts/access/Ownable.sol:48:5:
       |
    48 |     modifier onlyOwner() {
       |     ^ (Relevant source part starts here and spans across multiple lines).    

Questions:
How can I resolve the event naming conflict between Chainlink's and OpenZeppelin's OwnershipTransferred events?
What's the best way to handle the data location mismatch in fulfillRandomWords without breaking the VRF functionality?
How should I approach the multiple inheritance conflicts for ownership-related functions and modifiers?
Are there any best practices or recommended patterns for integrating Chainlink VRF v2.5 with OpenZeppelin contracts to avoid these conflicts?
Any insights or solutions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!


To resolve the event naming conflict between Chainlink's and OpenZeppelin's OwnershipTransferred events, you can avoid extending or inheriting the Ownable contract, instead utilize the required functionalities from VRFConsumerBaseV2Plus contract because it's  inheriting the ConfirmedOwner contract. Or, you can even define your own functionalities like onlyOwner, transferOwnership, etc. as per the requirement.
contract LazyPizzeria is ERC721Enumerable, ReentrancyGuard, VRFConsumerBaseV2Plus {

  // Rest of the code

  constructor(address _vrfCoordinator, bytes32 _gasLane, uint256 _subscriptionId, uint32 _callbackGasLimit) ERC721("LazyPizza", "LZPZ") VRFConsumerBaseV2Plus(_vrfCoordinator) {
    // Constructor body
  }
}


To handle the data location mismatch in fulfillRandomWords, replace memory with calldata in the second argument i.e., randomWords array:
function fulfillRandomWords(uint256 requestId, uint256[] calldata randomWords) internal override {

     // Function Body

}




Yes, thanks a lot Syed! I'd to so some other changes but now all the tests are passing. I'm getting an issue when deploying myself on Sepolia actual network though. Need to create a new issue

You’re welcome, @GiulianoMariaLodi. Kindly please mark the answer as accepted, if it helped you.

And, please feel free to open a new question mentioning the issues that you’re facing on Sepolia testnet, and share the link of the question over here in the comments.

Thank you! It should be marked as solved now :)  this is the link to the new issue
and thanks in advance wherever you could find a solution to it...
https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/164621/chainlink-vrf-v2-5-integration-fails-on-sepolia-but-passes-in-local-and-forked-t
